# How to Fix Client Error: file_get_contents(): in Cpanel with Laravel Project inside

Tags: laravel, hosting, cpanel

i have problem when do seed in my laravel project in cpanel.
this is the errors

```
Client Error: file_get_contents(): https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0

at vendor/kavist/rajaongkir/src/HttpClients/BasicClient.php:74
     70▕ 
     71▕     private function executeRequest(string $url): array
     72▕     {
     73▕         set_error_handler(function ($severity, $message) {
  ➜  74▕             throw new BasicHttpClientException('Client Error: '.$message, $severity);
     75▕         });
     76▕ 
     77▕         $rawResponse = file_get_contents($url, false, $this->context);
```

Please Someone help me

this is my LocationsTableSeeder.php

```
public function run()
{
    $daftarProvinsi = RajaOngkir::provinsi()->all();
    foreach ($daftarProvinsi as $provinceRow) {
        Province::create([
            'province_id' => $provinceRow['province_id'],
            'nama' => $provinceRow['province'],
        ]);
        $daftarKota = RajaOngkir::kota()->dariProvinsi($provinceRow['province_id'])->get();
        foreach ($daftarKota as $cityRow) {
            Kabupaten::create([
                'province_id' => $provinceRow['province_id'],
                'city_id' => $cityRow['city_id'],
                'nama' => $cityRow['city_name'],
                'type' => $cityRow['type'],
                'postal_code' => $cityRow['postal_code'],
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are using kavist/rajaongkir somewhere and that requires `allow_url_fopen` to be enabled

Comment: I've tried adding `allow_url_fopen = On`, `allow_url_fopen = 1`, and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

It's a good practice to disable `file_get_contents` ability to open remote URLs (like the ones starting HTTP) on shared servers (that frequently use Cpanel) to avoid the download/injection of malicious scripts in your server.

Go to Cpanel PHP options and enable `allow_url_fopen`, as pointed by apokryfos, usually it's at `Switch To PHP Options` menu.  Some providers will not allow this change via Cpanel and you might need to open a support ticket.

Usually, this option cannot be changed by `ini_set` or via the PHP script itself in any other way.